# big memory needs

Tags: memory-management

recentry we had task to need big amount of memory (RAM)
but have hot enought...

but we have much free HDD space

maybe exists tools (linux) which can handle process memory request (etc)
and have limit RAM swap it into HDD (like 'nice' tool handle priority)?

Comment: You are talking simply about a large virtual memory space.  The OS will do this for you automatically.  You may have to explain to the OS that it is OK for your process to use a lot of VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "much"? If "much" is more than a handful of GB:s, you need to be on 64-bit hardware and operating system, in order for a process to be able to address that large an amount of storage.

I'm pretty sure you can use virtual memory on 64-bit Linux at least, to provide apps with more storage than there is RAM. Of course, it won't be fast if the access pattern is random.

Comment: yes, much in my current definition is 64bit platform. Do you mean under virtual memory? is it swap?